# Looking for an HTML IDE where clicking on an element in the live preview highlights the code

Tags: html, ide, highlight, preview, live

I'm looking for an HTML IDE (preferably free) or extension for Visual Studio Code that:
a)has a live preview feature
and
b) clicking or right-clicking an element in the live preview highlights the corresponding code.
This seems to be a bit elusive, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me considering how useful this is.
I'm currently using Visual Studio Code with the Live Preview extension, but it doesn't allow doing anything with the preview.

Answer (score 0):

1, Adobe Dreamweaver, just use Split Mode.
You code yourself, just use the Editor part as a Live Preview so you won't mess-up with redundant and ugly codes.
You click on the code, and the live preview corresponding element will be highlighted, you click on the live preview, the text cursor will jump to the code.

2, Brackets
It just works exactly like what you want, but unfortunately, it is discontinued by Adobe.

3, Five servers (VSC Extension)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server
It is only one-way-highlight. You can't jump to code by clicking on Live Preview.
I haven't found any VSC extension working the way you want.